# How to kill items in minecraft 1.12.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi I would like to kill dropped items.

I've tried all these commands:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] Sample_OBJ 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:gold_block}}
/kill @e[type=Item,score_Sample_OBJ_min=1]
/scoreboard objectives add Sample_OBJ dummy

/kill @e[Item]
```

So far, none of these worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to create the scoreboard before you can use it. So `/scoreboard objectives add Sample_OBJ dummy` is the first command you need to use.
2. If that still doesn't work, try to replace `{id:minecraft:gold_block}` with `{id:"minecraft:gold_block"}`.
3. If you want to kill all items, the command is `/kill @e[type=item]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first add an objective before you can set scores using it (manually type in chat):

```
/scoreboard objectives add Item dummy
```

Use a repeating / unconditional / always active command block to set the score of the items to be killed to 1:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] Item 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_block"}}
```

**Note:**  Notice the quotes around `minecraft:gold_block`.

Use a chain / conditional / always active command block to kill any item with a score of 1:

```
/kill @e[type=Item,score_Item_min=1]
```

This will kill any dropped gold blocks.